# Get row and column number from Pandas Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the row and column number based on a given condition. The "coordinates" if you will.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,21,8,44,np.NaN,6,75,8,44,999], 
                    'B' : [1,1,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','AA1233445', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Assign','Hello','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Testing','Unicycle','Pharma','Unicorn',]})
print(dfp)

       A    B           C            D           E
0    1.0  1.0   AA1233445     123456.0      Assign
1   21.0  1.0   AA1233445     123456.0      Assign
2    8.0  3.0       rmacy    1234567.0       Hello
3   44.0  5.0    Idaho Rx   12345678.0        Ugly
4    NaN  0.0    Ab123455      12345.0  Appreciate
5    6.0  0.0    TV192837      12345.0        Undo
6   75.0  NaN          RX   12345678.0     Testing
7    8.0  9.0  Ohio Drugs  123456789.0    Unicycle
8   44.0  0.0     RX12345    1234567.0      Pharma
9  999.0  0.0  USA Pharma          NaN     Unicorn
```

I can get my output by doing:

```
print(dfp.loc[dfp['B'].isnull()].index.values[0] + 1 ,
',', + int([i for i,x in enumerate(dfp.columns.tolist()) if x == 'B'][0] + 1))
```

but the issue is if `B` had multiple nulls. I would like the coordinates for all nulls.

Is there a way to do this using `dataframe.loc` or something similar? Adding a 1 to the values is not a big deal, I can do that easily later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
dfp[pd.isnull(dfp['B'])].index.tolist()
```

For adding `1`concisely you could use:

```
np.asarray(dfp[pd.isnull(dfp['B'])].index) + 1
```

print

```
print(np.asarray(dfp[pd.isnull(dfp['B'])].index) + 1)
```

To include the index of column B (`dfp.columns.get_loc("B") + 1`):

```
for x in np.asarray(dfp[pd.isnull(dfp['B'])].index) + 1:
    print(str(x)+','+str(dfp.columns.get_loc("B") + 1))
```

To find "NaN"s in a given list of columns:

```
def find_NaN(list_col):
    for c in list_col:
        if c in dfp.columns:
            for x in np.asarray(dfp[pd.isnull(dfp[c])].index) + 1:
                print(str(x)+','+str(dfp.columns.get_loc(c) + 1))

find_NaN(["A","B"])
5,1
7,2
```

**Some explanations**

`dfp[pd.isnull(dfp['B'])]` selects data from the dataframe using an array of boolean values.

`dfp.columns.get_loc(c)` gives the index of column `c`

```
def find_NaN(list_col):
    for c in list_col:
        # if column is one of the dataframe's columns
        if c in dfp.columns:
            # for each index x where column c of the dataframe is null
            for x in np.asarray(dfp[pd.isnull(dfp[c])].index) + 1:
                print(str(x)+','+str(dfp.columns.get_loc(c) + 1))
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it does not give me the correct values. The answer should be 6,1 or 7,1 (if adding the 1). This gives me 6, 8 or 7,9

Comment: @MattR I added a function to find NaNs for a list of columns

Comment: This is awesome. Way better than what I had even thought of. I hope to get as good as you and piRSquared some day. IF you have extra time (notice the caps), could you add a comment or two on what each part of the code is doing? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a combination of `np.where` and `zip`

```
i, j = np.where(dfp.isnull().values)

# Coordinates in the space of the actual index and column names
list(zip(dfp.index[i], dfp.columns[j]))

[(4, 'A'), (6, 'B'), (9, 'D')]
```

Otherwise, stick to ordinal positions with

```
list(zip(i, j))

[(4, 0), (6, 1), (9, 3)]
```

Or

```
np.column_stack([i, j])

array([[4, 0],
       [6, 1],
       [9, 3]])
```

Comment: I also like this approach, but what would be the correct way to filter the condition to specific columns? this is currently searching for nulls in the entire database. I only want the (6,1) coordinate because column `B` is null

Comment: @MattR `np.where(dfp.B.isnull().values)[0]`

Comment: I tried that as well, but I get an `IndexError`. and if I use `np.where(dfp.B.isnull().values)[0][0])` then it is not interable. PS: I hope to have your skills some day. you're always answering my questions haha